# Libreoffice—How to disable dual-page display

Tags: libreoffice

How do you turn off the two-panel display in Libreoffice? It's so annoying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bottom right corner, there are 3 icons, the first one has only one page.

Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, thanks! Why is that program is so full of label-less picture icons—it's a wonder I can find anything.

Comment: Wrong, that stops working once office is closed. But I found a workaround — it is enough to shrink office window size, and the office automatically shows only one page, even when in the corner two pages set. Windows size, at least, being saved on close.